# How to import data from XML to PDF Form using Delphi ?

Tags: xml, delphi, import, delphi-10.2-tokyo, pdf-form

I have a PDF File filled with text, arrays, images etc.. but also with textfields.

**I would like to know if and how is it possible to import a correctly formatted XML File in order to fill these textfields such as *Name, Surname, Address...***

**I simply want to do something like this action from the menu in Acrobat Reader : *Edition- Form options - Import data*  but using Delphi programming.**

I presume that I will need to open the PDF and use a function to parse the XML file in order to fill the form but for now I didn't find any good advice on the web explaining how to do such thing.

I hope my question is correct and it will be possible for you to answer me.

Best regards.

Comment: This is trivial to do in the full version of Acrobat, by importing its COM objects into an interface unit and then creating them at runtime.  Maybe recent versions of Reader have a similar possibility.

Comment: @MartynA Thank you for you answer, so I kinda understand it but I don't see how to do it in Delphi code.

Comment: Well. one of the Acrobat COM object libraries is form filling in forms.  You generate a Delphi import unit (something_tlb.pas) from the type library and then just instantiate the objects in it to fill the forms in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some example code which uses the form-filling COM objects of Acrobat to fill in Acrobat fields from XML data parsed using the XML Partner library from Turbopower.  It's not compilable as is because of some external dependencies, and in need of a bit of refactoring, but it should give you the general idea.  The `Calibrate` routine adds some markings to assist field placement.

```
unit AcrobatXMLu;

interface

uses
  [...]
  Acrobat_tlb, //  main Acrobat COM wrapper
  AFORMAUTLib_TLB;  // Acrobat Forms COM objects

type
  TGenerateFlag = (gfShowAcrobat, gfUseDefaultValues, gfGenerateTestData, gfAddCalibration, gfAlwaysFillCheckboxes);
  TGenerateFlags = set of TGenerateFlag;

function CreateAcrobatFieldsInner(eStartNode: TxpElement;
  const Path: String; Flags : TGenerateFlags; const OutputFile : String): Boolean;

implementation

function CreateAcrobatFieldsInner(eStartNode: TxpElement;
  const Path: String; Flags : TGenerateFlags; const OutputFile : String): Boolean;
var
  List : TxpNodeList;
  X : TxpNode;
  N,
  Max : Integer;
  E : TxpElement;
  Align,
  S : String;
  AddedFields : TStringlist;

  procedure CreateField(E : TxpElement);
  var
    FieldName,
    FieldType,
    MappedFieldType : String;
    PageNo : Integer;
    ALeft,
    ARight,
    ATop,
    ABottom,
    AWidth,
    AHeight : Single;
    S : String;
    Field : IField;  //  Acrobat form field
    IsMultiLine : Boolean;
  begin
     FieldName := E.GetAttribute('Name');
     if CompareText(FieldName, 'Name1') = 0 then
       NoOp;
     FieldType := LowerCase(E.GetAttribute('PdfFieldType'));
     MappedFieldType := FieldType;
     if CompareText(MappedFieldType, 'checkbox') = 0 then
       MappedFieldType := 'text';
     IsMultiLine := CompareText(MappedFieldType, 'memo') = 0;
     if (CompareText(MappedFieldType, 'Text') = 0) or (CompareText(MappedFieldType, 'Memo') = 0) then
       MappedFieldType := 'text';

     Align := LowerCase(E.GetAttribute('Align'));
     S := E.GetAttribute('Page');
     if S = '' then
       S := TxpElement(E.ParentNode).GetAttribute('Page');
     if S <> '' then
       PageNo := StrToInt(S) - 1
     else
       PageNo := 0;
     S := GetHeritableAttribute(E, 'XPos', 'FieldXPos');
     ALeft := StrToInt(S);

     ATop := E.GetAttributeInt('YPos');

     S := GetHeritableAttribute(E, 'Width', 'FieldWidth');
     if S <> '' then
       AWidth := StrToInt(S)
     else
       AWidth := 60;
     S := GetHeritableAttribute(E, 'Height', 'FieldHeight');
     if S <> '' then
       AHeight := StrToInt(S)
     else
       AHeight := 20;
     ARight := ALeft + AWidth;
     ABottom := ATop - AHeight;

     try
       Field := Acrobat.Fields.Add(FieldName, MappedFieldType, PageNo, ALeft, ATop, ARight, ABottom) as IField;
       if True or (AddedFields.IndexOf(FieldName) < 0) then begin
         if CompareText(MappedFieldType, 'text') = 0 then begin
           S := GetHeritableAttribute(E, 'TextFont', 'FieldTextFont');
           if S <> '' then
             Field.Set_TextFont(S);
           S := GetHeritableAttribute(E, 'TextSize', 'FieldTextSize');
           if S <> '' then
             if not (CompareText(S, 'Auto') = 0) then
               Field.Set_TextSize(StrToInt(S));
           if IsMultiLine then
             Field.Set_IsMultiline(True);

           S := E.GetAttribute('DefaultValue');
           S := StringReplace(S, #10, #10#13, [rfReplaceAll]);
           if S <> '' then begin
             Field.Set_Value(S);
           end
           else begin
             if CompareText(FieldType, 'checkbox') = 0 then begin
               if gfAlwaysFillCheckboxes in Flags then
                 Field.Set_Value('X')
             end
             else begin
               if gfGenerateTestData in Flags then
                 Field.Set_Value(Format('(%s)', [FieldName]));
             end;
           end;
           if Align <> '' then
             Field.Set_Alignment(Align);
         end
         else begin
           if CompareText(MappedFieldType, 'checkbox') = 0 then begin
           end;
         end;
       end;
       if AddedFields.IndexOf(FieldName) < 0 then
         AddedFields.Add(FieldName)
     except
       ShowMessage('Error adding field ' + FieldName);
     end;
  end;

  procedure Calibrate;
  var
    X,
    Y,
    N,
    M,
    Page : Integer;
    Field : IField;  // Acrobat form field

    procedure AddField(X, Y : Integer);
    var
      S : String;
      FieldName : String;
    begin
      if X < 40  then
        S := Format('Y:%d', [Y])
      else
        S := Format('X:%d', [X]);
      FieldName := Format('X%dY%d', [X, Y]);
      Field := Acrobat.Fields.Add(FieldName, 'text', Page, X, Y, X + 40, Y - 15) as IField;
      Field.Set_TextFont('Courier');
      Field.Set_TextSize(10);
      Field.Set_Value(S);

    end;
  begin
    for Page := 0 to ((Acrobat.AcroApp.GetActiveDoc as CAcroAVDoc).GetPDDoc as CAcroPDDoc).GetNumPages - 1 do begin
      for N := 1 to 15 do
        AddField(40 * N, 0);
      N := 15;
      for M := 0 to 60 do
        AddField(0, N * M);
    end;
  end;

begin
  AddedFields := TStringlist.Create;
  AddedFields.Sorted := True;
  Result := False;
  try
    List := eStartNode.SelectNodes(Path);
    try
      Max := List.Length - 1;
      for N := 0 to Max do begin
        X := List.Item(N);
        if not (X is TxpElement) then Continue;
        E := TxpElement(X);
        S := E.GetAttribute('YPos');
        if S <> '' then
          CreateField(E);
      end;
      Result := True;
    finally
      List.Free;
    end;
    if gfAddCalibration in Flags then
      Calibrate;
    Acrobat.DocV.GetPDDoc.Save(PDSaveFull, OutputFile);
  finally
    AddedFields.Free;
  end;
end;

end.
```

As written, this code adds the fields defined in the XML and fills them in as it goes along.  Obvious;ly it is a trivial matter to fill in existing fields instead.

Some of the 3rd party PDF libraries for Delphi may also be able to fill in Acrobat fields.  Also the command-line library PDFtk can also fill in Acrobat fields and do other things the Acrobat COM objects cannot, like "flattening" a PDF form, which effectively merges the text in the fields into the host document and so no longer editable as a form.  See https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/ for more info.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will get into it and try everything. It seems to give me the answer or at least a very good line to follow. Thanks again